# Pressing browsers back button, url is not stored in the history stack?

Tags: php, redirect, browser, header, browser-history

On button click I navigate the user to an other url. When I click the browser back button it sends me the page before the button has been clicked. I checked the history, and the page, where I hit the button is not present. I tried to use

```
header("location: url")
<?php echo "<script>window.location.href=url</script>"; ?>
```

Both navigated the right url, but the last page is not in the history stack!
On every other pages it works. This is the only page where it doesn't.

Comment: Why don't use  `window.history.back();` ?

Comment: Because I dont want to go back. After click the button i redirect the user to a new page. If the user clicks the back button on the browser, it doesn't send him back the last page where he clicked the button, but 2 pages before. I check the browser history, and i cant see, the url i click the button is missing. In short, it is left from the history stack!

Comment: You sent any data like POST method ?

Comment: No, I dont use form, I use session to store data. But the url is changing, so it still should work.

Comment: why don't use another button for go back ?

Comment: I have a button like that too and it works. But I want to manage the history back button as well, I cant leave it like that :D  On every other page it works, except this one.

Comment: Are you sure in the prev. page you didin't nothing special?

Comment: Nothing i didnt use before. A simple header redirect :( I can't get it